# restrict to store duplicate values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb for my application and i am facing a problem like a field is accepting duplicate values as well which i dont want

I want to know how to restrict it
I have followed an approach by specifying `unique :true` for a field `quesListName`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var QuestionListSchema = new Schema({
    topicName: String,
    quesList: {
        quesListName: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        by: String
    }
});
```

but still it is accepting the duplicate value

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: try to restart mongo

Comment: Your `quesList` is not a list, but just an object. What kind of duplicates do you actually get? Can you make an example?

Comment: or refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354834/mongoose-unique-true-not-work

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the unique for the index:

```js
var QuestionListSchema = new Schema({
    topicName: String,
    quesList: {
        quesListName: {
            type: String,
            index: {
              unique: true
            }
        },
        by: String
    }
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index

Comment: Thanks this worked for me 
With this i did another mistake i.e; i havent created index for that field 
btw it is fixed now :)